# Unable to assign message from delivery callback block in rabbitmq with java

Tags: java, rabbitmq, message-queue, producer-consumer

I am trying to consuming a message from RabbitMQ using Java-Maven. I am able to get and print the message inside delivery callback block, but unable to assign the value to any global variable.

Please look at the issue below,

```
public String newRmqConsumer(String queue) {

    String QUEUE_NAME = queue;
    String response = null;

    System.out.println("****** Consumer service ******");

    try {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setUsername("queueone");
        factory.setPassword("queueone");               
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        factory.setPort(4545);

        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();               

        System.out.println("Queue Name: "+QUEUE_NAME);              
        System.out.println("1. Consuming Message...");

        String getMsg;  
        DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
            String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), "UTF-8");   
            getMsg = message;
            System.out.println( "2. \"" + message + "\" message received");
        };
        response = channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> { });                     
    } catch (IOException e) {       
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {          
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

Error:

> Local variable getMessage defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Comment: Why do you want to assign to a variable outside the deliver callback? This callback is executed for *every* message consumed. What is the use case to overwrite a variable for every message consumed?

Comment: Because I want to read the consumed message. Please let me know any other way.

Comment: You already read the message as `String message` inside `deliverCallback`. You handle it by just printing it. You should extend the body of `deliverCallback` to do more with the consumed message than just printin it. What is it you want to do based on the consumed message?

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper because you can't change local variables inside of a lambda function.
Any kind of wrapper is good.

With Java 8+, use either an AtomicReference:

```
AtomicReference<String> value = new AtomicReference<>();
list.forEach(s -> {
  value.set("blah");
});
```

Use an array:

```
String[] value = { null };
list.forEach(s-> {
  value[0] = "blah";
});
```

Or with Java 10+:

```
var wrapper = new Object(){ String value; }
list.forEach(s->{
  wrapper.value = "blah";
});
```